# Multiplicar el valor de un input por el de una lista mostrada con ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Tengo un arreglo de datos que muestro con un ng-repeat dentro de una tabla.

Esto llena 4 campos de los 5 que tengo actualmente declarados, el siguiente es un INPUT en el cual obtengo el valor de piezas solicitadas por el cliente.

Mi pregunta claramente sería: ¿cómo puedo multiplicar el valor del input (que son las piezas solicitadas por el cliente) por el precio que está dentro de la lista?.

También la cuestión es que necesito que ese valor se albergue dentro de una variable llamada `total`.

Está es mi vista (inicio.html):

```
<div class="container">
<table class="table table-bordered table-condensed">
        <tr>
            <th>Nombre</th>
            <th>Existencia</th>
            <th>Precio</th>
            <th>Solicitado</th>
        </tr>
        <tr ng-repeat="producto in productos" ng-class="{'ocultar' : producto.ocultar}">
            <td>{{producto.nombre}}</td>
            <td>{{producto.existencia}}</td>
            <td>{{producto.precio | currency }}</td>
            <td><input type="number" ng-model="solicitado" min="1" max="5000" ng-change="comprar(producto)"></td>
            <td><h1>{{solicitado}}</h1></td>                
        </tr>           
        <tr>
            <td>Total de pedido: {{obtenerTotal()}}</td>
        </tr>
</table>


<h5></h5>
<button class="btn btn-success" ng-click="total()">Calcular Pedido</button> 
</div>
```

Esté es mi controlador

```
miAppAngular.controller('inicio', ['$scope', function ($scope) {

    $scope.saludo = "Carlos";
    $scope.solicitado = "";

    $scope.productos = [
        {
            id:1,
            nombre:"Negro Azulado 1",
            existencia: 20000,
            precio: 45
        },
        {
            id:2,
            nombre:"Negro Luminoso 2",
            existencia: 20000,
            precio: 45
        },
        {
            id:3,
            nombre:"Castaño Oscuro 3",
            existencia: 20000,
            precio: 45
        },
        {
            id:4,
            nombre:"Castaño Medio 4",
            existencia: 20000,
            precio: 45
        },
        {
            id:5,
            nombre:"Castaño Claro 5",
            existencia: 20000,
            precio: 45
        },
        {
            id:6,
            nombre:"Rubio Oscuro 6",
            existencia: 20000,
            precio: 45
        },
        {
            id:7,
            nombre:"Rubio Medio 7",
            existencia: 20000,
            precio: 45
        },
        {
            id:8,
            nombre:"Rubio Claro 8",
            existencia: 20000,
            precio: 45
        },
        {
            id:9,
            nombre:"Rubio Claro Claro 9",
            existencia: 20000,
            precio: 45
        },
        {
            id:10,
            nombre:"Rubio Extra Claro 10",
            existencia: 20000,
            precio: 45
        },
        {
            id:11,
            nombre:"Castaño Cenizo Claro 5.1",
            existencia: 20000,
            precio: 45
        },
        {
            id:12,
            nombre:"Rubio Cenizo Oscuro 6.1",
            existencia: 20000,
            precio: 45
        },
        {
            id:13,
            nombre:"Rubio Cenizo Medio 7.1",
            existencia: 20000,
            precio: 45
        },
        {
            id:14,
            nombre:"Rubio Cenizo Claro 8.1",
            existencia: 20000,
            precio: 45
        },
        {
            id:15,
            nombre:"Rubio Cenizo Claro Claro 9.1",
            existencia: 20000,
            precio: 45
        },
        {
            id:16,
            nombre:"Rubio Cenizo Extra Claro 10.1",
            existencia: 20000,
            precio: 45
        },
        {
            id:17,
            nombre:"Rubio Nacarado Medio 7.2",
            existencia: 20000,
            precio: 45
        },
        {
            id:18,
            nombre:"Rubio Nacarado Cenizo Claro 8.21",
            existencia: 20000,
            precio: 45
        },
        {
            id:19,
            nombre:"Rubio Nacarado Claro 9.2",
            existencia: 20000,
            precio: 45
        },
        {
            id:20,
            nombre:"Rubio Nacarado Cenizo Extra C 10.21",
            existencia: 20000,
            precio: 45
        }
    ]


    $scope.carrito = [];


    $scope.comprar = function (_item){
        _item.ocultar = true;

        $scope.carrito.push(_item);

    }

    $scope.obtenerTotal = function(){
        var total = 0;
        for (var i = 0; i < $scope.producto.length; i++) {
            var producto = $scope.producto[i];
            total += carrito.producto;
        }
        return total;
    }

}])
```

Comment: ¿Cómo eliges cuál precio usar para la multiplciación?

Answer (score 0):

En el arreglo de listado de productos a cada elemento agrega dos propiedades mas:

```
$scope.productos = [
        {
            id:1,
            nombre:"Negro Azulado 1",
            existencia: 20000,
            precio: 45,
            cantidad: 0, //De esta manera
            total: 0 //De esta manera
        },
        {
            id:2,
            nombre:"Negro Luminoso 2",
            existencia: 20000,
            precio: 45,
            cantidad: 0, //De esta manera
            total: 0 //De esta manera
        }
];
```

Y en el `ng-model` del input establece de la siguiente manera `ng-model="producto.cantidad"` cuando mandes a llamar el método de **comprar() con el ng-change**

```
$scope.comprar = function (_item){
        _item.ocultar = true;
        _item.total = _item.cantidad * _item.precio;

        $scope.carrito.push(_item);

    }
```

El siguiente código:

```
<td>Total de pedido: {{obtenerTotal()}}</td>
```

cámbialo por esto:

```
<td>Total de pedido: {{precioTotal | currency}}</td>
```

Y vas a crear la siguiente función en el controlador para calcular el Pedido

```
$scope.total = function(){
    $scope.precioTotal = 0;
    $scope.productos.map(function(producto){
       $scope.precioTotal += producto.total;
    });
}
```